# Can't send SoftwareSerial to Class Object

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, softwareserial

I have a problem when I try to use SoftwareSerial in a class..

**Here my detail** My class

```
class MyEsp8266
{
 protected: 
     SoftwareSerial *esp8266;
 public: 
     MyEsp8266(SoftwareSerial *_esp8266){
           esp8266 = _esp8266;
     }
     void begin(int baud){
        esp8266->begin(baud);
     }
     String testAT(){
          esp8266->println("AT");
          return esp8266->readString();
     }
}
```

**My Arduino code**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "MyEsp8266.h"
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board

SoftwareSerial _esp(10, 11);
MyEsp8266 wifi(&_esp);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    wifi.begin(115200);
    Serial.println(wifi.testAT());
}
```

It doesn't log anything **But** when I have used all code in Arduino code it worked.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board

SoftwareSerial _esp(10, 11);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    _esp.begin(115200);
    _esp.println("AT");
    Serial.println(_esp.readString());
}
```

Thank any tips. 
Regards.

Comment: You forgot to print the return value of `wifi.testAT();`...?

Comment: it my mistake when post question I have updated it

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a work-around than a solution, but the code you're trying to get to work, worked for me once I changed

```
wifi.begin(115200);
```

to

```
wifi.begin(9600);
```

(sorry I don't have enough karma to just comment)

Comment: Hi **baud 115200** worked with secondary code.

Comment: I agree! and when testing your desired block of code, I got it to output the test line by changing the baud from 115200 to 9600.

Comment: I think that means your Wifi module use baud 9600.

Comment: To clarify, I was using the bluetooth HC-05 which a quick Google search tells me It can go up to 1382400. But besides, I tried both code samples, the second worked without modification (meaning my hardware can handle 115200) and then when I tried the first, and once I changed the baud to 9600 it worked. Did adjusting the baud rate on the first code sample not fix the problem for you?